# Function selector for constructor & fallback function?

Tags: abi, function-selector

According to https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Ethereum-Contract-ABI, function selector is hashed from function name and list of its arguments put inside `()`.

For example, with function `deposit(uint value)`, the function selector is Keccak hash of string `deposit(uint256)`

However, it is not clear in the case of **constructor** & **fallback** functions: what should be strings - to be hashed - for below 2 cases?

```
constructor(address addr) public { }

function () payable public { }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

The constructor cannot be called. It's only run once: at the deployment of the smart contract.

The fallback function can be called using just `call()` with no signature, or with any signature that does not belong to any other `public` or `external` function of the contract. Hence the name 'fallback'.

Comment: I see, but then when I looked into the bytecode, i can see the contract looks for this function selector: `7c2efcba`. My contract only has 2 functions above, then why it looks for this selector, if neither constructor & fallback functions has signature?

Comment: The 4 bytes of Keccak hash for "()" is `861731d5`, which does not match this `7c2efcba` function selector signature, so I must misunderstand you?

Comment: How about `bytes4(keccak256("")`? So, the keccak256 hash of an empty string

Comment: I get back `c5d24601` on empty string "". What is your result?

Comment: Not including a dummy selector is bad practice. See my answer here for a better explanation of fallback behavior: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/123382/36872